# Получение копии экрана с удаленного компьютера

Tags: delphi

Как в Delphi получать копию экрана с удаленного компьютера с помощью IP адресcа? Спасибо вам большое заранее! :)

Comment: Без наличия на удаленном компьютере сервера, который отдаст эту копию — невозможно. При наличии — уточняйте, что за сервер/протокол.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий. С помощью TCP/IP.
Мне не поставили никаких условий. Учителю нужен результат :)))

Answer (score 2):

Никак. Для этого как минимум необходимо разбить программу на два компонента: серверную и клиентскую части. Но про это в условии задачи ни слова не было.

Касательно реализации могу предложить такие варианты:

- пишете свой видеодрайвер, который будет получать изображение рабочего стола в реальном времени и транслировать в сеть;
- или используйте уже существующий в винде сервис RDP (remote desktop) и пишете к нему свой клиент

Comment: Ну зачем же сразу драйвер? На мой взгляд, тут достаточно сделать некий "сервер", который по запросу будет отдавать "скриншот" экрана. Делается с помощью функции `bitblt`.

Answer (score 2):

Мой вариант получения скриншота с удалённого компьютера. В приложении-клиент, которое и будет принимать скриншот, размещаем компонент IdTCPClient с закладки IndyClients (первый по умолчанию). Настраиваем свойства: Host - IP-адрес компьютера-сервера, Port - целое число (кроме нуля) - например - 1234. В коде подключаемся к серверу так:

```
IdTCPClient1.Connect;// Можно написать этот код на кнопку "Подключиться"
```

Отключаемся, соответственно, так:

```
IdTCPClient1.Disconnect;// Можно написать этот код на кнопку "Отключиться"
```

Получить скриншот в таком случае так:

```
procedure TClientMainForm.N7Click(Sender: TObject);
Var
  fStream: TFileStream;
begin
  If Not (IdTCPClient1.Connected) Then Exit;
  IdTCPClient1.WriteLn('screenshot');
  fStream:=TFileStream.Create(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0))+'screenshot.jpg',
    fmCreate);
  IdTCPClient1.ReadStream(fStream);
  fStream.Free;
  Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0))+'screenshot.jpg');
end;
```

Теперь приложение-сервер. На нём самым главным будет компонент IdTCPServer с закладки IndyServers. Понадобится глобальная переменная: MS: TMemoryStream; в разделе Var.
Код для события OnCreate формы:

```
MS:=TMemoryStream.Create;
```

Для OnDestroy, соответственно:

```
MS.Free;
```

Код для кнопки "Создать сервер" (или для события OnShow формы):

```
  IdTCPServer1.Bindings.Add;
  IdTCPServer1.Bindings.Items[0].IP:='здесь пишем IP-адрес компьютера-клиента';
  IdTCPServer1.Bindings.Items[0].Port:=1234; { Порт должен быть и на сервере и на клиенте одинаковым! }
  IdTCPServer1.Active:=True; // запуск сервера
```

Код для кнопки "Уничтожить сервер" (или для события OnClose формы)

```
  IdTCPServer1.Active:=False; // выключаем сервер
  IdTCPServer1.Bindings.Delete(0);
```

А теперь обработчик события OnExecute для компонента IdTCPServer:

```
procedure TMainServerForm.IdTCPServer1Execute(AThread: TIdPeerThread);
Var
  Str: String; // строка
  Bmp: TBitmap; // BMP формат
  Jpg: TJpegImage; // JPG формат
  SDC: hDC;  // для работы с экраном
  SCan: TCanvas; // холст экрана
  fStream: TFileStream; // для файлика (скриншота)
begin
  With AThread.Connection Do
    Begin
      Str:=ReadLn;
//-------Делаем скриншот----
  If (Str='screenshot') Then
    Begin
      SDC:=GetDC(0); // Доступ к экрану
      SCan:=TCanvas.Create; // создаю холст экрана
      SCan.Handle:=SDC; 
      Bmp:=TBitMap.Create; // создаю объект: изображение в формате BMP
      Bmp.Height:=Screen.Height; // подгоняю размеры изображения
      Bmp.Width:=Screen.Width;
      Bmp.Canvas.CopyRect(Rect(0, 0, Bmp.Width, Bmp.Height), SCan,
        Rect(0, 0, Screen.Width, Screen.Height)); // скопировал экран
      ReleaseDC(0, SDC);
      SCan.Free; // освобождаю холст
      //----из BMP в JPEG конверт---
      Jpg:=TJpegImage.Create; // создаю объект
      Try // Блок Try можно при желании опустить, но лучше, я думаю, оставить
        Jpg.Assign(Bmp); // изображение в него
        Jpg.SaveToFile(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0))+'screenshot.jpg'); // сохраняю
      Finally
        Jpg.Free; // выгружаю объект
        Bmp.Free; // выгружаю объект
      End;
      //----- отправляю клиенту скриншот
      fStream:=TFileStream.Create(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0))+
        'screenshot.jpg', fmOpenRead+fmShareDenyNone);
      OpenWriteBuffer;
      WriteStream(fStream, True, True);
      CloseWriteBuffer;
      fStream.Free;
    End;
End;

Str:='';
end;
```

На наблюдаемом компьютере можно сделать приложение-сервер невидимым и автозапуск его, например, через реестр, если, конечно так нужно.

Comment: Спасибо вам за помощь:)))Я ету задачу решила по  етой же схемы но в Дельфи 5. Моя курсавая готова! Спасибо всем:)))